# Oracle / windows hardware recommendation

Tags: oracle

I'm specifying a Windows server to run Oracle for (time based) performance tests of our application.

Although the total data volume & number of users will be low, we would like the performance to be comparable to a high-powered server which is hosting many users & much more data; in other words the type of machine a large enterprise client would have.

My questions are:
- is this realistic, can we get comparable performance?
- if so, any things to look out for in the server specification?

Many thanks

Comment: Fast disks, running RAID 10. Lots of RAM. Reasonable CPU. Those are first prize.

Comment: Product and service recommendations are specifically off topic for ServerFault (see point 4 in the NOT About section of the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just setup some HP DL380 G6 servers for a departmental level Oracle database.

8 cores, i7, 12+ GB of RAM.
8 15k rpm disks in a 2u rack mount.

We got ours for about $AUD 15,000

Not sure what your budget is though... ideas vary about what is 'enterprise' level.

Answer (score 0):

I would aim for the enterprise level hardware, then something like Swingbench / Hammerora to generate accurate data volumes and load levels. If the application is well designed, it should scale. If it is poorly designed, it may work wonderfully for small data/user levels then fail miserably when trying to scale up.